# How to pass HashMap Value through an Instance?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, hashmap, instance

I am creating Fragment depends on retrieving of Category Count from Server.
If it has 5 Category, 5 Tab Fragment has to be created.For this, I used the following code.

Here values1 is the Category Id & Category Name is values.

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return TabFragmentSearch.newInstance(values1.get(position), values.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabName.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return values.get(position);
        }
    }
```

**return TabFragmentSearch.newInstance(values1.get(position), values.get(position));**

Now insteadof passing **ArrayList values1 & value** I need to use & pass **HashMap**  Value via Instance. What do I need to do.

Your help is more appreciated...

UPDATE:
ERROR

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should implement new method newInstance(HashMap values) or change existing in your TabFragmentSearch class

Comment: Yeah I tried.But when I change it shows like the snap that I uploaded.